# removing element from list

Tags: java, list

I have 2 lists, and depending on a parameter I remove an element from 1 of the 2 lists.  I then loop through the lists for additional processing.  However even though the list has lost 1 element, the `list.size()` is still the same causing a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
    System.out.println(high_list_price.size());

    if(first_hit.equals("low")){
        high_list_date.remove(high_list_date.size()-1);
        high_list_price.remove(0);
        high_list_percent.remove(0);
    }
    if(first_hit.equals("high")){

        low_list_date.remove(low_list_date.size()-1);
        low_list_price.remove(0);
        low_list_percent.remove(0);
    }

    System.out.println(high_list_price.size());

    for(int tt = 0;tt < low_list_date.size();tt++){
        System.out.println(low_list_date.get(tt)+"|"+low_list_price.get(tt));
    }

    for(int ii = 0; ii < high_list_date.size();ii++){
        System.out.print(high_list_date.get(ii)+"|");
        System.out.println(+high_list_price.get(ii));
    }
```

high_list_price.size() = 51 both before and after the .remove, yet high_list_date.size() goes from 51 to 50, why is that?

Comment: `array.size()`? In any case, did you actually remove anything? `size()` will return the current size.

Comment: How are you creating these lists?  Are they backed by arrays?

Comment: I suspect you error does not come from the code you have pasted here. It must be something else.

Comment: The code you posted has no error in it (other than when size() returns 0).  consider posting the code that you replaced with an ellipsis in the loops.

Comment: I suspect, given the methods you're calling from your array that you are actually using an ArrayList already.  I don't remember remove or size being things you could use for an array.  Is this correct?  If not, your problem would probably stem from arrays not being re-sizable.  You will need to figure out the new size needed for your array, create a new array and dump the information from the old array into the new array.  As mentioned by previous posters, it would be easier to use an ArrayList or vector.

Comment: @kelleystar OP must be using List or at least some collection, otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Commas are important.  My sentence should have read "I suspect, given the methods you're calling from your array, that you are actually using an Arraylist already".  Mea culpa.  I meant to acknowledge that he was probably already using a list and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate through ArrayLists backwards, you can delete the current element without worrying about what comes after.
Another option is to iterate through, make a list of things to delete, then delete those elements form the original list.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the valid options provided by @z5h there, consider using the `Iterator` interface, which includes a `remove()` method that removes the item from the underlying collection without causing the kinds of problems that using `Collection.remove()` causes.

Using `Iterator` might help you walk through your collections in a more readable fashion, as well.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an plain array. It provides additional functions like `remove(Object o)`